# how to remove div if class count is greater than x in jquery?

Tags: jquery, clone, slice

I'm wondering if there is a way to remove a div based on (1) the class and (2) the count?  I was looking at slice(), but I can't figure out how to get it to work with the html I'm forced to use...

Below is the HTML and below that is the jquery code. (The add-book button is at the very bottom) I commented the jquery code to try and explain what I'm trying to do... (I also posted it at: http://jsfiddle.net/n00b0101/kW2vR/)

```
<div class="s-item">
    <!-- Form for Book 0 -->
    <div class="s-form">
        <div class="form-item"><input type="text" name="book[0]" value="" /></div>

        <div class="b-item">
            <div class="form-item"><input type="text" name="book[0][title][0]" value="" /></div>
            <div class="form-item"><input type="text" name="book[0][subtitle][0]" value="" /></div>
            <div class="form-item"><input type="text" name="book[0][author][0]" value="" /></div>
        </div>

        <div class="b-item">
            <div class="form-item"><input type="text" name="book[0][title][1]" value="" /></div>
            <div class="form-item"><input type="text" name="book[0][subtitle][1]" value="" /></div>
            <div class="form-item"><input type="text" name="book[0][author][1]" value="" /></div>
        </div>

        <div class="b-item">
            <div class="form-item"><input type="text" name="book[0][title][2]" value="" /></div>
            <div class="form-item"><input type="text" name="book[0][subtitle][2]" value="" /></div>
            <div class="form-item"><input type="text" name="book[0][author][2]" value="" /></div>
        </div>      

        <div class="book-buttons"><input type="button" name="book-0-add" value="Add Item" /></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Form for Book 1 -->
    <div class="s-form">
        <div class="form-item"><input type="text" name="book[1]" value="" /></div>

        <div class="b-item">
            <div class="form-item"><input type="text" name="book[1][title][0]" value="" /></div>
            <div class="form-item"><input type="text" name="book[1][subtitle][0]" value="" /></div>
            <div class="form-item"><input type="text" name="book[1][author][0]" value="" /></div>
        </div>

        <div class="b-item">
            <div class="form-item"><input type="text" name="book[1][title][1]" value="" /></div>
            <div class="form-item"><input type="text" name="book[1][subtitle][1]" value="" /></div>
            <div class="form-item"><input type="text" name="book[1][author][1]" value="" /></div>
        </div>

        <div class="book-buttons"><input type="button" name="book-1-add" value="Add Item" /></div>
    </div>  
</div>

<div class="new-book-button"><input type="button" name="add-book" value="" /></div>
```

Here is the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name=add-book]').click(function() {
        addAdditionalBook();
    }
});

function addAdditionalBook() {
    var totalForms = $('.s-form').length; //Yields 2;
    var sFormsItems = $('.s-form:first > .b-item').length; //Yields 3

    //Trying to
    //Step 1 : Clone the first s-form
    var newForm = $('.s-form:first').clone();

    //Step 2: Keep only the first b-item... Will slice work here? 
    //When I try to use slice, I can't get it to just deal with .b-items

    newForm = ???

    //Step 3: Increment the ids and names for book x
    $(newForm).find('*').each(function() {
        if( $(this).is(':input') ) {
            var bookName = $(this).attr("name");
            $(this).attr("name", bookName.replace(/book-0/,'book-'+totalForms).replace(/book_0/,'book_'+totalForms).replace(/book\[0/,'book['+totalForms));
        }

        var sid = $(this)[0].id;    
        $(this).attr('id', sid.replace(/book-0/,'book-'+totalForms).replace(/book_0/,'book_'+totalForms).replace(/book\[0/,'book['+totalForms));
    });

}
```

**So, after all is said and done, I should wind up with this html:**

```
<div class="s-item">
    <!-- Form for Book 0 -->
    <div class="s-form">
        <div class="form-item">Book Title: <input type="text" name="book[0]" value="" /></div>

        <div class="b-item">
            <div class="form-item">Book Chapter: <input type="text" name="book[0][chapter][0]" value="" /></div>
            <div class="form-item">Book Subtitle: <input type="text" name="book[0][subtitle][0]" value="" /></div>
            <div class="form-item">Book Author: <input type="text" name="book[0][author][0]" value="" /></div>
        </div>

        <div class="b-item">
            <div class="form-item">Book Chapter: <input type="text" name="book[0][chapter][1]" value="" /></div>
            <div class="form-item">Book Subtitle: <input type="text" name="book[0][subtitle][1]" value="" /></div>
            <div class="form-item">Book Author: <input type="text" name="book[0][author][1]" value="" /></div>
        </div>

        <div class="b-item">
            <div class="form-item">Book Chapter: <input type="text" name="book[0][chapter][2]" value="" /></div>
            <div class="form-item">Book Subtitle: <input type="text" name="book[0][subtitle][2]" value="" /></div>
            <div class="form-item">Book Author: <input type="text" name="book[0][author][2]" value="" /></div>
        </div>      

        <div class="book-buttons"><input type="button" name="book-0-add" value="Add Item" /></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Form for Book 1 -->
    <div class="s-form">
        <div class="form-item">Book Chapter: <input type="text" name="book[1]" value="" /></div>

        <div class="b-item">
            <div class="form-item">Book Chapter: <input type="text" name="book[1][chapter][0]" value="" /></div>
            <div class="form-item">Book Subtitle: <input type="text" name="book[1][subtitle][0]" value="" /></div>
            <div class="form-item">Book Author: <input type="text" name="book[1][author][0]" value="" /></div>
        </div>

        <div class="b-item">
            <div class="form-item">Book Chapter: <input type="text" name="book[1][chapter][1]" value="" /></div>
            <div class="form-item">Book Subtitle: <input type="text" name="book[1][subtitle][1]" value="" /></div>
            <div class="form-item">Book Author: <input type="text" name="book[1][author][1]" value="" /></div>
        </div>

        <div class="book-buttons"><input type="button" name="book-1-add" value="Add Item" /></div>
    </div>  

    <!-- Form for Book 2 -->
    <div class="s-form">
        <div class="form-item">Book Chapter: <input type="text" name="book[2]" value="" /></div>

        <div class="b-item">
            <div class="form-item">Book Chapter: <input type="text" name="book[2][chapter][0]" value="" /></div>
            <div class="form-item">Book Subtitle: <input type="text" name="book[2][subtitle][0]" value="" /></div>
            <div class="form-item">Book Author: <input type="text" name="book[2][author][0]" value="" /></div>
        </div>

        <div class="book-buttons"><input type="button" name="book-2-add" value="Add Item" /></div>
    </div>      
</div>

<div class="new-book-button"><input type="button" name="add-book" value="Add Book" /></div>
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do, but to keep one out of many, have a look at .not() (http://api.jquery.com/not/)

Comment: If I understood correctly, you're cloning the elements from form1, and then removing what you don't need... So, why not just copy the parts that you need?

Comment: can you describe your intentions with the page please? Is it possible to detect the number of classes on an element? Sure, just grab the actual "class" attribute (using JS) split it on " " and check the length. But we could probably suggest a much better way to do what you have in mind. Including more semantic html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
newForm = ???
```

with

```
newForm.find(".b-item:not(:first)").remove();
```

to remove all but the first b-item from the new Form.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I get that you want to clone the form, then keep the first `.b-item` from that form? If that is correct, you can do this:

```
//Step 1 : Clone the first s-form
var newForm = $('.s-form:first').clone();

//Step 2: Keep only the first b-item... 
var firstItem = newForm.find('.b-item:first');
```